# Kendo UI Grid: pagination is not working

Tags: kendo-grid

I've got a table:

```
<table id="grid">
<thead>
    <tr><th data-field="name">Name</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr><td>name 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>name 2</td></tr>
    ...
</tbody>
</table>
```

That's how it's inialized:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    autoBind: true,
    columns: [ { field: 'name' } ],
    pageable: {
        buttonCount: 5,
        pageSizes: [10, 20, 50, 100, 200]
    },
    pageSize: 20
});
```

When page is loaded, grid shows all elements. For example, if there are 500 elements, all of them are shown. Page number is equal 1, but it's not highlighted. PageSize switcher shows "500". When I click on PageSize switcher and change it to any value, pagination starts to work. Or if I click on prev/next page icon, it works, too. How could it be fixed?

Now I use this:

```
if ($grid.data("kendoGrid")) {
    $grid.data("kendoGrid").dataSource.page(1);
}
```

But I'm not sure it's good enough.

Comment: Did you figure out how to fix this by chance?  I just ran into the same problem.

Comment: One observation is that you are missing a Total value which represents the total number of elements.

An example could be
 schema: {
    total: function(response) {
      return 100000000;
    }

Answer (score 0):

pageSize is a property of the Data Source not kendoGrid, although the Kendo documentation (as of today) has pageSize as a property of KendoGrid, in their examples you will see it in the DataSource.

not to confuse with "pageSizes" which is in the correct position.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    scrollable: false,
    sortable: true,
    autoBind: true,
    columns: [ { field: 'name' } ],
    pageable: {
                   refresh: true,
                   pageSizes: true
                    },
    pageSize: 20
});
```